# Why does this ordering filters out elements of a set?

Tags: scala

Here is the code:

```
object Test {
  import collection.mutable.TreeSet
  val myOrdering = Ordering.fromLessThan[Int](_ > _)
  val set1 = TreeSet(3, 2, 1, 5)(myOrdering) // 5, 3, 2, 1
  val myOrdering2 = Ordering.fromLessThan[Int](_ % 3 > _ % 3)
  val set2 = TreeSet(7, 4, 2, 3, 1, 5)(myOrdering2) // TreeSet(5, 1, 3)
}
```

Intuitively one would expect `set2` to be something like `TreeSet(5, 2, 7, 4, 1, 3)`, but Scala filters out "duplicates" because `5 % 3 == 2 % 3` etc. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

No, `TreeSet` uses the `Ordering` to assess equality as well. `Ordering.equiv` is equivalence, which is called by `TreeSet`.